# Trying to Import Plotly into my React application using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plotly, plotly.js

I tried following the instructions provided in the top answer here [react plotly js with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518749/react-plotly-js-with-typescript/70807520#70807520)
but am encountering a type error now. I promise I ran both `npm i plotly.js react-plotly.js` and `npm i --save-dev @types/plotly.js @types/react-plotly.js`

[image]

The test code I'm trying to run is from the top answer in the link above.